# Plesk : Subdomains can't render a PHP file

Tags: php, plesk

I created a subdomain in plesk and tried to upload an **index.html** with some text on it, It renders well.

However, when I tries to upload an **index.php** with a basic text on it, it shows

```
Forbidden

You do not have permission to access this document.
```

The same error that shows when my subdomain folder is empty. At the same time it downloads a file which contains my index.php code.

Anyone have some idea about this? thank you in advance

Comment: Is there an option when creating the subdomain/account to enable PHP?

Comment: there's no option for that